# Question about the theorem of highest weights

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have some confusion from reading [Theorem 7.3 in Sepanski's Compact Lie groups](https://books.google.com/books?id=F3NgD_25OOsC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=highest%20weight%20theory%20theorem%207.3%20Sepanski&source=bl&ots=DDBz7IJTlD&sig=yJeI4XIF6ZeLtFgcf02JbvbkLfs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YDhjVa65EvTasASj74HYCg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=highest%20weight%20theory%20theorem%207.3%20Sepanski&f=false) and would appreciate it if someone could clarify.

1. In part (e) the book says "for $w\in W$, $wV_\lambda=V_{w\lambda}$, so that $\dim V_\lambda=\dim V_{w\lambda}$."

My first question is how do we make sense of the action of the Weyl group $W$ on a weight space $V_{\lambda}$?

(For the proof of part (e), the book refers  to the proof of a similar equality for root spaces that I do understand, but I think it is does not carry over from root spaces to weight spaces  to give $wV_\lambda=V_{w\lambda}$, no matter how we interpret the left-hand side of this equality.)

2. My second question is about the "connectedness" assumption in the theorem. Isn't this assumption redundant?

Thanks for reading!